# SQL - Exclude rows based on field value in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having difficulty with excluding entire rows in my inner joined table based on a field value in another table. Here's what I mean:

Distinct IDs (TableA Inner Join TableB)

```
    ID    |     Date     |    Bldg_Nbr   
----------+--------------+------------------
     1    |  10/20/2014  |       92       
     2    |  10/20/2014  |       92      
     3    |  10/20/2014  |       92       
     4    |  10/20/2014  |       92       
     5    |  10/20/2014  |       92
```

Code Table (TableC)

```
    ID    |     Date     |    Code    |    Bldg_Nbr   
----------+--------------+------------+----------------
     1    |  10/20/2014  |     11     |       92
     1    |  10/20/2014  |     02     |       45
     3    |  10/20/2014  |     15     |       85
     3    |  10/20/2014  |     95     |       66
     4    |  10/21/2014  |     11     |       92
```

What I want to do is exclude the ID rows in the Inner Joined table that have a code 11 with the same date and bldg number listed in the Code Table (TableC). Note that the Code Table (TableC) can have an ID with many different codes with the same date and/or bldg. In this example I would want ID 1 excluded, but not ID 4 since it has a different date.

Here's the code for the first table (TableA Inner Join TableB) which works; I just need to incorporate the TableC constraints:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
          I.DATE,
          I.BLDG_NBR,
          I.ID
FROM TableA I 
INNER JOIN TableB D ON I.ID = D.ID  
WHERE I.DATE = '20-OCT-2014' AND I.BLDG_NBR = 92
```

Comment: You might need to tell more about relation of this table.. i.e. what is the foreign key here?

Comment: It's still not clear - you want to exclude regardless of the ID of TableC or IDs in inner joined table and TableC should match?

Comment: The IDs in the inner joined table and TableC need to match. I want to exclude Distinct ID records IF there is a corresponding record (based on ID) in TableC with a Code = 11, Date = 10/20/2014, Bldg_Nbr = 92. In the example above, I would only want ID 1 excluded (ID 4 has a code 11 but the date = 10/21/2014).

Answer (score 0):

This will exclude code 11 rows in the Inner table that have the bldg_nbr and date in the code table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    I.DATE, 
    I.BLDG_NBR, 
    I.ID    
FROM TableA I INNER JOIN TableB D 
    ON I.ID = D.ID
    AND I.Bldg_Nbr = D.Bldg_Nbr
    AND I.Date = D.Date
    AND D.Code != 11

WHERE I.DATE = '20-OCT-2014' 
AND I.BLDG_NBR = 92
```

Comment: Thanks! ... I guess I didn't include this in the question but I already inner joined TableA and TableB. I'd like to take that inner joined table and exclude rows based on another table (let's say TableC) which contains those codes.

Comment: You just need to join the results from your first join to the third table identifying the filtering elements. Like this: SELECT * from table A a join Table b on something join C on something else;

Comment: The issue with the code above is that the separate Code Table (TableC) is not called out. D.Code doesn't exist in TableB, it's in TableC.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.DATE, I.BLDG_NBR, I.ID
FROM TableA I
     INNER JOIN TableB D ON I.ID = D.ID
WHERE I.DATE = TO_DATE('20-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND I.BLDG_NBR = 92 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableC C WHERE C.ID = I.ID AND I.DATE = C.DATE AND I.BLDG_NBR = C.BLDG_NBR AND C.CODE = 11)
```